# What does @ mean before a variable?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I have this assignment:

```
$buffer=@data_value[$i];
```

what does the @ mean?

Comment: It's to prevent you from figuring out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Actually that statement does not even compile

Comment: @Ignacio I second that.  Our phpcs code standards are configured to pick up any developers trying to do this and yell at them.

Comment: @nico: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in...`

Comment: Top tip - Only use the error suppressor when you absolutely have to - a reasonable example being a file operation you expect to fail, want to fail silently and intend to check yourself post-operation.

Comment: @nico - no, it doesn't, there's no $ on data_value.

Comment: should be: `$buffer=@$data_value[$i];`

Comment: @kemp: None of my PHP code compiles!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That prevents any warnings or errors from being thrown when accessing the `i`th element of `data_value`.

See [this](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/19/8/12) post for details.

Answer (score 5):

The `@` will suppress errors about variable not being initialized (will evaluate as `null` instead).

Also, your code is probably missing a $ after @:

```
$buffer=@$data_value[$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called the "error-control operator". Since it's an assignment, I believe you should do the rest yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**the `@` in front of a statement means that no warnings/errors should be reported from the result of that statement. To put simply, *Error Reporting* is suppressed for this statement.**

This is particularly useful, when e.g. `@fclose(fopen("file.txt",w"))` which can throw several warnings/errors depending on the situation, but with an `@` in front of it, all these warnings or errors will be suppressed.

Comment: It's less often useful than not.

Comment: Agreed. What I meant here was, this is useful when you are in a production environment and do not want to show error reports to end-user.

Answer (score 0):

As above, it suppresses the error if the array key doesn't exist.  A version which will do the same without resorting to dodgy error suppression is

```
$buffer = array_key_exists($i, $data_value) ? $data_value[$i] : null;
```

Comment: That's just error suppression via syntactic salt, not a significantly different outcome.

Comment: No, it's correctly checking that a value exists before attempting to make use of it.