# What does the @ character do in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [What does @ mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621215/what-does-mean-in-php)

I have a line in my code which looks like this:

@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Error: Unable to select database");

It works, but I want to know what the @ does and why it is there.

Comment: In a great quote I saw recently, "it prevents you from finding out what's wrong with your program".  I think it was Gordon...

Comment: @ElYobo dont think it was me, but there is much truth in it

Comment: @Gordon, you should have stayed quiet and took the credit then ;)  It was somewhere here on SO, but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: @ElYobo it was [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393201/what-does-mean-before-a-variable) in the duplicate before this duplicate. I remember I linked it in the reference :)

Comment: "@Gordon, you should have stayed quiet..." Given the question, I find this funny.

Comment: @Aether hehe, yeah, but I have [scream](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.scream.php) enabled by default ;)

Comment: @Gordon, nice detective work.  @Aether, you just made me spill my coffee :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the `@` will suppress the regular PHP database connection error (which may contain sensitive information). In case of a connection error, the "or die" part will be executed, failing with a generic error message. The line is probably copied from a "quick and dirty" example.

Using the error suppression operator `@` is considered bad style, especially when other forms of error handling are missing. It complicates debugging - how can you find out about in error without any indication that it occured? In a production system it's better to log all errors to a file and suppress the rendering of errors on the page. You could do that in the `php.ini` file or (if you are on a shared host and not allowed to make config changes) with the following code.

```
ini_set('display_errors', false);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/apache/php-errors.log');
```

Comment: @ will suppress *every* error, not just database connection errors.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 13):

The `@` symbol suppresses any errors and notices for the expression it precedes.

See this reference: [PHP Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

> PHP supports one error control
>   operator: the at sign (@). When
>   prepended to an expression in PHP, any
>   error messages that might be generated
>   by that expression will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It suppresses all error output. Generally, you shouldn't use it unless you have a good reason. I don't know why it is used in the example you posted, or why die() is used. The error should be caught and processed accordingly. The select may fail for a number of reasons, some perhaps recoverable. Like no connection to the database established.